# Event being declared as Delegate

Tags: c#, events, c#-4.0

While going through C# example codes, I have found this declaration:

```
public event myEventHandler myEvent = delegate { };
```

What does this statement mean? It is not inline with other declarations of delegate I have seen on internet.

Answer (score 2):

```
public event myEventHandler myEvent = delegate { };
```

Assigns an function to the event when an instance of the class is created by simply delegating it with anonymous function.
When assigning a function to event's invocation list, the following notation is used

```
myClass.myEvent += delegate { };
```

However the following assignment is also valid inside the parent class, but it basically discards all the existing invocation list unless it is used in `ctor`.

```
myEvent = delegate {};
```